# Cleaning up PHP code, trying to find a difference in an if clause and continue

Tags: php

We want to get rid of the continue in this code, and i replaced it easily, seemed to work for a few procedures and then started creating differences. From what i've read this should work just fine, but i'm wondering if anyone can state a difference in the workings of the code found below.

```
    while (list($key, $value) = each($row)) 
{   
if (($key=="addressID") AND (!array_key_exists($value, $aAddress)))
    {
        continue 2;
    }
  //do code here
}
```

and

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($row)) 
{   
    if (!(($key=="addressID") AND (!array_key_exists($value, $aAddress))))
    {
      //do code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for us to see the loop that is wrapping the while loop shown?

Comment: Unlucky having to inherit that code. What does '2' do?

Comment: `continue 2` iterates a loop two levels up; yours just conditionally executes code.

Comment: When using `continue 2` or `break 2`, it will break out of `2` loops rather than just 1. I assume there is another loop that we are not seeing.

Comment: Bah I got confused in my head between continue and goto (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) neither of which I have ever actually used.

Comment: Yeah, this is coming from no experience with PHP either so im pretty out of my element. The while loop is in another while loop that loops through an SQL database.

Comment: Wont continue go to the end of the while loop shown in the first block of code?

Comment: If it's a matter of it breaking out of one more loop than i had expected, then it might be an easy fix with the code i have

Answer (score 1):

You must check [php manual for continue again](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) 
You are using `continue 2;` to exit from the shown while loop and the the one not shown in your code.

Using `if` clause you are just omitting the part in the present loop while the one outside is still being run.
To have your code run the same you'll have to place the check on the outer loop too so that the outer loop is also running conditionally.

I tried hard to find something simple but not able to find a way out you can use the conditional flag like this:

```
while() {          //your outer loop

  while() {  //your innner loop
    if (!(($key=="addressID") AND (!array_key_exists($value, $aAddress))))
    {
      //do code here
    }
    else {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(flag==1) {
    flag = 0;
    continue;
  }
  else {
    // your echo code goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what im gathering from others, and if so then it should be an easy fix, i thought from reading the explanatory files, that continue would exit to the loop i had originally shown.

Comment: Moreover your code is XSS prone please use prepared statements.